# NSIS scripting --- Creating a custom page

Tags: nsis

I'm new to NSIS. This is the script given by a developer. Here it is reading "xpath" and "logonpath" from $EXEDIR\env.ini and writing to setup.ini, which is further read by installer.

Here I was getting error on compiling, that there is no setup.ini file -> File: "setup.ini" -> no files found. Then I created a blank setup.ini file in script folder. Error is gone but custom page is not generated while installing.

Looks like something needs to put in setup.ini file, which I'm mising.
Please help.

Below I have added env.ini  file structure for reference.

```
; Script generated by the HM NIS Edit Script Wizard.

; HM NIS Edit Wizard helper defines
!define PRODUCT_NAME "Test"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "1.0.0"
!define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "Test1"
!define PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Test"

SetCompressor lzma
; X64 compatibility
!include "x64.nsh"
; include for some of the windows messages defines
!include "winmessages.nsh"
; HKLM (all users) vs HKCU (current user) defines
!define env_hklm 'HKLM "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"'
!define env_hkcu 'HKCU "Environment"'

; MUI 1.67 compatible ------
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "InstallOptions.nsh"

; MUI Settings
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_ICON "Vessel.ico"

; Welcome page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
; License page
; !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "License.txt"


!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
; Directory page
;!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
var XPath
var logonPath
LangString XDRIVE_TITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Enter the Test setup details"
LangString XDRIVE_SUBTITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "X Drive setup"
page custom defineXDrive
; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
; Finish page

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

; Language files
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

; MUI end ------

Function .oninit
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_EXTRACT_AS "setup.ini" "setup.ini"

System::Call 'kernel32::CreateMutexA(i 0, i 0, t "myMutex") i .r1 ?e'
Pop $R0
StrCmp $R0 0 +3
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "The installer is already running."
Abort

FunctionEnd

Function .onInstSuccess
MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION "It's strongly suggested you restart the \
  computer to finalize settings.$\nDo you want to restart?" IDNO +2
    Reboot
FunctionEnd

Function defineXDrive
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "$(XDRIVE_TITLE)" "$(XDRIVE_SUBTITLE)"
push $R0
push $R1
ReadINIStr $R1 "$EXEDIR\env.ini" "setup" "xpath"
ReadINIStr $R0 "$EXEDIR\env.ini" "setup" "logonpath"
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_WRITE "setup.ini" "Field 4" "State" "$R0"
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_WRITE "setup.ini" "Field 5" "State" "$R1"
pop $R0
pop $R1

# Display the page.
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY "setup.ini"

# Get the user entered values.
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $logonPath "setup.ini" "Field 4" "State"
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $XPath "setup.ini" "Field 5" "State"
FunctionEnd

Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
OutFile "Test-Setup-19c_test.exe"
InstallDir "C:\Test"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" ""
ShowInstDetails show

Section "Platform" SEC01
;......
SectionEND
```

env.ini structure

```
 `[setup]
 env="UAT"
 xpath=\\APPSRV1\UAT
 logonpath=http://APPSRV1/test/core/auth`
```

This is the custom page, which need to be generated after reading setup.ini file

[image: This is the custom page, which need to be generated on reading setup.ini file]

Comment: Maybe complete your previous ini related question before asking another one?

Comment: Hi Anders.. previous one is quite confusing.. I m going through NSIS documents to understand. But this question I need to workout first. Please help. This will be highly appreciated..thanks in advance..

Comment: Your example code contains a lot of unnecessary stuff, perhaps you could clean it up a bit?

Comment: unnecessary stuffs: removed

Comment: Got the solution: using using this ini file   #setup.ini structure                                                       
[Settings]
NumFields=5

[Field 1]
Type=Label
Left=10
Right=-40
Top=10
Bottom=18
Text=Please input the following details for Test

[Field 2]
Type=Label
Left=10
Right=-160
Top=55
Bottom=65
Text=Logon URL:

[Field 3]
Type=Label
Left=10
Right=-160
Top=40
Bottom=50
Text=X Drive network drive:

[Field 4]
Type=text
State="xpath"
Left=150
Right=-20
Top=55
Bottom=65

[Field 5]
Type=text
State="logonpath"
Left=150
Right=-20
Top=40
Bottom=50